# Help to remove vertical space between text and table

Tags: tables, spacing

i need to remove this vertical space from the text and the table. Here are a screen of the results that i want to change
[image]

See the space between the word "sono" and the table, it's too much and i want it to get closer to the table. I will also add the script:

```
\uppercase{è} stato inoltre effettuato  il calcolo dei  valori della funzione Quantile Loss per i due modelli, i risultati sono:

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
```

I've tried different solutions like `\vspace{-0.5em}` or `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` or `\vfill` but this didn't change anything. Can you help me?

EDIT 1:
I was trying to do a whole new document to answer some of your question, while doing that i found out that if i add only a portion of the whole work i don't have the issue, i don't know why. I didn't change a single line of code,Any idea now?
I add screen of the new results
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: The primary function of [H] format is to cause large gaps in your document.  Forcing the table to follow immediately is a side effect ;-)

Comment: [H] certainly do not help to reduce document gaps, but your chunk of code completed with the minimum to obtain a compilable  code do not show that problem. Our divination skills end here.  We need see a whole document where we can reproduce the issue, but obviously short. Remove **everything** in your working document as long as it does not prevent the compilation *and* will not change that gap. Then replace your minimal required text  with dummy text (very easy with the help of the `lipsum` package,  search examples in this site) and post the whole document.

Comment: What follows the table?  If it is something that won't fit on the page, so it goes to the next page, that is a very frequent reason for excess space above a float positioned [H], and it usually can't be fixed just by tinkering with the spacing.  We don't have enough information to give an informed or useful answer.

Comment: `\uppercase{è}`? Are you ***really*** sure? Why not `È`? If your editor or keyboard doesn't allow to type it, change them. Anyway, please, provide a full compilable example showing the issue.

Comment: Guys sorry for the late update, but i have to tell also this news. I was trying to do the document to reproduce the issue, and i found out that if i add a portion of the whole work i don't have this issue, do you have any idea why?

Comment: @marco: From what you've mentioned, understand that it would be difficult for the community to provide an answer since we can't reproduce it. We don't have your "whole document" so can't reproduce it that way. The only way forward really is to provide more context or detail.

Comment: After my edit i tried different solution and i figured It out It was a problem Linked with the spacing of the whole document, the paging etc. Ty for your answes anyway

Answer (score -1):

I suspect the table environment is messing with the spacing.  Without seeing all the code, I would suggest removing the \begin{table}  \centering.  I would then put the remaining \begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular} inside a \begin{center} ... \end{center}.  That way you would have more control over the vertical spacing.

So something like

\uppercase{è} stato inoltre effettuato  il calcolo dei  valori della funzione Quantile Loss per i due modelli, i risultati sono:

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
...
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, this helped with the spacing but now i cant give a name to the table, is there a way to mix the solutions?

Comment: Hy, can you see the update and help me ?